# Converting rows to columns using crosstab in PostgreSQL not working (relation "table" does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, subquery, pivot, materialized-view

I need to use the compiled data using CTE and then convert the columns to rows using crosstab(open to other ideas) in the next select statement. Below is the query.

```
  with checked_adgroup AS (
     SELECT 
        ua.new_adgroup,
        ua.account,
        ua.campaign,
        ua.ad_group,
        ua."position",
        cp.category,
        pt.full_value,

       FROM unnest_adgroup ua
         LEFT JOIN taxonomy_category cp ON ua."position" = cp."position"
         LEFT JOIN taxonomy pt ON ua.short_val = pt.short_value AND cp.category = pt.category AND (pt.lob IS NULL OR pt.lob = ua.lob)
    )

SELECT * 
from crosstab(
'select
cad.account,
cad.campaign,
cad.ad_group,
cad.category,
cad.full_value
FROM checked_adgroup cad 
WHERE  cad.all_correct AND cad.category IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1,2,3')
AS final_result( 
 account text, campaign text, ad_group text,
 division text, lob text, match_type text  )
;
```

**Error message:**

**ERROR:  relation "checked_adgroup" does not exist
LINE 7:     FROM checked_adgroup cad**

Output of checked_adgroup cte looks like below 
[image]

Desired output of the final statement is:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use the crosstab function to begin with. This is typically a lot easier with filtered aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The CTE is not visible inside the `crosstab()` function. You have to pass the complete query string including the CTE.

Possible alternative: create a temporary table instead of the CTE.

However, there are more problems in your query. `all_correct` seems undefined. Etc.

Basic instructions:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)